# Tkinter, py - Creating a game where everytime you click a button a new button appears

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I want to start out with `Button1`, you click `Button1` and `Button2` is created, you click `Button1` or `Button2` and `Button3` is created, and so on until you click the correct button(currect button will be a random button number)

This is what I have so far but all this does a create a new button with the name `Button1`

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")

def add_button():
     start_button.pack_forget()
     count = 0
     count = count + 1
     text_button = "Button%s"%(count)
     i = Button(root, text=text_button,command = add_button)
     i.place(x=random.randint(350, 600), y=random.randint(400, 600))

var=StringVar()
banner = Message(root, textvariable=var, relief=RIDGE)
var.set("Click a button\nThe more buttons you click, the more buttons get     added.\nClick the correct button to win!")
banner.pack()
start_button = Button(root, text='Start Game',command = add_button)
start_button.pack()

root.mainloop()

#create multiple buttons after start button is selected
#tell player the number to win changes every time
#add a timner
#add for i in number of buttons  to choice a random button number that wins
#add a win screen
#have it show time
#add a quit game button at bottom
```

Comment: You are setting `count` to zero every time `add_button()` is called.  That value needs to be stored outside of the function (a global variable, for example) so that it can actually change over time.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.  It's important in Python.  Easiest is to paste the original code between ``` or ~~~ marks

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining your `count` variable every time you call `add_button()`, meaning that every time you call this function, the count goes back to zero. To fix this, just define the variable outside the function, so replace your `add_button()` function to this instead:

```
count = 0
def add_button():
     start_button.pack_forget()
     count = count + 1
     text_button = "Button%s"%(count)
     i = Button(root, text=text_button,command = add_button)
     i.place(x=random.randint(350, 600), y=random.randint(400, 600))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to add `global count` at the beginning of `add_button()`.